# וְהִתְקִין לוֹ מִמֶּנּוּ בִּנְיַן עֲדֵי עַד Is the translation of מִמֶּנּוּ **His** very self or his very self?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, creation, text, sheva-brachos

The Koren Sacks siddur translates the 4th of the 7 wedding blessings as:

> אֲשֶׁר יָצַר אֶת הָאָדָם בְּצַלְמוֹ, בְּצֶלֶם דְּמוּת תַּבְנִיתוֹ,
>   וְהִתְקִין לוֹ מִמֶּנּוּ בִּנְיַן עֲדֵי עַד:
>
> who fashioned humanity in His image, the image of His likeness and out
>   of **His** very self formed a building for eternity. (emphasis added)

Note the capital H in the bolded “His”. It implies that Hashem made the “building for eternity” out of His self and not, as I imagined, out of Adam. Is this a misprint or is there an interpretation I need to learn?

Comment: +1 this sounds so wrong. I'll eat my words if someone finds a source, but this sounds like pandering to the liberals, bordering on heresy.

Comment: Standard reading: "God made Adam, and then from Adam the woman who is a building for eternity." Sacks' reading: "God made humanity, and ... [thus?] a building for eternity.  Yeah that's a bit of a stretch. (Note that other denominations change the blessing to "Who made us" for gender-neutrality.) Note, however, that the Chizkuni already says the translation of "Adam" is "human."

Comment: לימוד זכות - It may be a typo, in that a vigilant editor hyper corrected "his" to "His."

Comment: Maybe there is a less common custom of capitalizing the first letter of "his" when it refers to _Adam ha-Rishon_: When translating the blessings as they appear in _Mishneh Torah Hilkhot Ishut_ 10:3, Eliyahu Touger [translates the quoted passage](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952884/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Ten.htm#footnoteRef9a952884) as "_who created man in His image, in an image reflecting His likeness; [He brought forth] his form and prepared for him from **His own Self** a structure that will last for all time_", ...

Comment: (cont.) ... but [footnote 10](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952884/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Ten.htm#footnote10a952884) says "_Rashi (ibid.) interprets this as a reference to the creation of woman, who was created from **man** ('**his own self**'), and gives him the potential for reproduction ('a structure that will last for all time')_" (All bold emphases are mine), suggesting that the capitalized words are referring to _Adam ha-Rishon_.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, Rashi ([Kesubos 8a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=8&format=pdf)) agrees with your intution:

> **והתקין לו ממנו:**  מגופו מצלעותיו
>
> **And he fashioned for him, from him:** From his body; from his ribs.

However, an alternate explanation is noted by [R. Aaron ben Jacob Hakohen of Lunel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_ben_Jacob_ha-Kohen) in Orchos Chaim ([Hil. Kiddushin § 21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49315&st=&pgnum=68)):

> **והתקין לו ממנו בנין עדי עד:** פי׳ הנפש השכלית
>    שנחצבת מגלגל תשיעי ועומדת לעד בקיומה שלא תכלה
>
> **And he fashioned for him, from him, an everlasting building:** Meaning the intellectual soul, carved from the ninth orbit and remaining forever in its state of existence so that it will not end.

According to this explanation, "building" refers not to Eve, but to the soul. Accordingly, "from *him*" presumably means from God, because presumably God did not make a soul for Adam, from Adam, and God is the only other entity mentioned in the blessing that "him" could refer to.

Thus, the siddur in question may follow this interpretation.

---

If I might add, this interpretation seems a bit far fetched, considering that the term "building" is explicitly employed by the biblical text in reference to the creation of Eve ([Genesis 2:22](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39996&st=&pgnum=26)) and not in reference to the soul (see [Genesis 2:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39996&st=&pgnum=22)).

Comment: The full quote is והתקין לו ממנו בנין עדי עד פי׳ הנפש השכלית
 שנחצבת מגלגל תשיעי ועומדת לעד בקיומה שלא תכלה. וי׳מ והתקין לו ממנו בנין
 עדי עד, על חוה כי מאיש לוקחת זאת. וממנו שב אל האדם. פי׳ מגופו ומצלעותיו.
according to the first pshat, we are not refering to Chava whatsoever.

Comment: Exactly. Are you disagreeing with something I wrote?

Comment: Just clarifying. But I will offer a question now. Why can't ממנו be refering to that גלגל תשיעי?

Comment: Presumably the blessing would not use a pronoun to refer to a being not identified anywhere else in the blessing. Therefore, "him" either refers to God or Adam.

Comment: Your doubt may be well placed, but Eve didn't live forever (while the soul does). So we aren't referring to EVE, we're referring to the SEPARATION INTO GENDERS, calling which a "binyan" is similarly questionable.

Comment: Fair point, although I still think the word "building" is so odd in context (where in Tanach is a soul, a body, or a gender called a "building?") that it only really fits if it has something to do with the creation of the woman, whom the text says was "built." Thus, even if you are correct that it doesn't refer to Eve specifically but to the human female gender in general, that concept still has a close connection with the "building" verse which is about the creation of the original human female, while the soul does not.

Comment: A valiant effort in defense of the capital H but contradicted by the Siddur's commentary: "The fourth [blessing] alludes to the second chapter of Genesis, in which God, seeing that the man was alone, formed 'out of His [sic] very self' a partner so that they could become 'a building for eternity' through their descendants."